# How Do I Go about Securing a Change in the Bounty Mechanism If Possible?

Tags: feature-request, community, moderation

During my periods of contribution, I frequently find myself editing posts to stave off closure. This is incentivized with the Copy Editor badges. An example of that is defending the notion that 'consent' is somehow a legal technicality with no place in philosophical Q&A. ([See When consent changes: can "consent" after the fact be valid? (PhilSE)](https://When%20consent%20changes:%20can%20%22consent%22%20after%20the%20fact%20be%20valid?).)

As I continue my participation to improve this wiki-style Q&A knowledge-base, I so with a very specific agenda of drawing traffic through quality entries, and on occasion offer bounties to raise awareness and draw quality contributions. **I would like additional leverage to do so.** Since this post [Is this site dying? (MetaPhilSE)](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5074/is-this-site-dying), it seems no concrete steps have been taken to change this trajectory.

Given the relatively low number of votes on Q&A compared to some of the more popular SE sites, I would like the mechanism to offer bounties modified so that instead of a 1-1 reputation cost, I might be able to award 1-5 or 1-10 to encourage more participation and activity on this site. **How would I go about making that happen**?

Comment: You’d have to make a case on [mse], but don’t hold your breath. You’re going to get a chilly reception there, most feature requests do, but that’s almost irrelevant as the people you need to convince are not the SE community but rather its employees who drive the product roadmap. You’d have to make a case compelling enough to prioritize this over other product improvements they’re already planning. In other words: you’re asking for a software change, and those are rare and slow to come when they do.